# Getting current page - Magento

Tags: php, magento

The thing is that I have logo displayed on only homepage in Magento checking if it's homepage with getIsHomepage();. Now the thing I want to do is to display logo inside header only on Dashboard page, do you know any alternative to getIsHomepage but to check if it's My account page?

Thanks

Comment: are you working on admin>dashboard ya customer account??

Comment: I'm talking about customer account on frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best practice to use xml to do this instead of parsing url. Add this to your local.xml:

```
<customer_account_index>
   <reference name="header">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/customer_account_header.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

And copy and edit your header.phtml file to `template/page/html/customer_account_header.phtml`

Comment: I have header defined for all pages as the same, will this override it?

Comment: Yes, this will overwrite for only the customer account page.

Comment: Gerard,  Nice to see someone on this board finally advocating for the use of a local.xml file!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to out logic for customer account page then

First fetch current routers and controllers and action to headere.phtml

logic is like 
for magento customer dasboard page url is customer/account/index

```
then 
<?php $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
echo $action->getFullActionName('_');
if($action->getFullActionName('_')=="customer_account_index")
{

}

?>
```